# Rails ActiveRecord Mongoid Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid

In my user model i have

```
field :contact_info, :default=>{}
field :info, :default=>{}
```

How could I create a User.new with `contact_info.[some key]`

`[some key]` being a key that the user would provide themselves